# How to Create Target(y) and X variables from CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, target

I am reading a CSV file and I am needing, for modeling purposes, to create a Target (Y) and X variables. Not sure how to set that up. I am new to coding and needing some guidance that I can't seem to understand from Pandas docs. I would like to have Target as 'Bad Indicator' and 'X' as all other columns.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
project = pd.read_csv('c:/users/Brandon Thomas/Project.csv')
project=pd.DataFrame(project)
df = pd.DataFrame(project.data, columns = project.feature_names)
df["Bad Indicator"] = x.target
X = df.drop("Bad Indicator",axis=1)   #Feature Matrix
y = df["Bad Indicator"]          #Target Variable
df.head()
```

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call 
    last)
     in 
          1 # Build dataframe
    ----> 2 df = pd.DataFrame(project.data, columns = project.feature_names)
          3 df["Bad Indicator"] = x.target
          4 X = df.drop("Bad Indicator",axis=1)   #Feature Matrix
          5 y = df["Bad Indicator"]          #Target Variable

```
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, 
name)
   5065             if 
self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5066                 return self[name]
-> 5067             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5068 
   5069     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code above you create a dataframe 3 separate times. Once with `pd.read_csv`, once with `project = pd.DataFrame(project)` and once more with with `df = pd.DataFrame(...)`. By default, `pd.read_csv` object will be a dataframe.

I have taken out currently unnecessary imports such as numpy, scipy, and matplotlib. You can add them back if you need them later. To set up Y and X, all you need to do is:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('c:/users/Brandon Thomas/Project.csv') # this will automatically name your columns if your csv has headers

#if your csv does not have headers:
df.columns = ['Bad Indicator', 'ColumnName1', 'ColumnName2',..]

X = df.drop("Bad Indicator",axis=1)   #Feature Matrix
Y = df["Bad Indicator"]          #Target Variable

df.head()
```

If your csv does have headers, remove the `df.columns` line.